# How to get the child of a view which is not having an id in android test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I want to open the navigation drawer with a click on the Hamburger menu [image: icon] during a test.

Currently the Hierarchy of the action bar is as follows:

```
...
Toolbar (@id/action_bar)
  TextView (no-id)
  ImageButton (no-id) <-- this is the hamburger menu
  ...
...
```

using Espresso there is only Matchers for `withId`, `withText`, etc. which doesn't serves my purpose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `allOf` and `withParent` to pinpoint that view:

```
onView(
    allOf(
      withClassName(is(ImageButton.class.getName())),
      withParent(withId(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.action_bar)))
  .perform(click());
```

More info: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/05/espresso-match-toolbar-title.html

Comment: Slight error, the `withClassName` accepts a string matcher, so the code should be `withClassName(is(ImageButton.class. getName()))`.

Comment: @AvinashR Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Turns out using a custom `ViewMatcher` will do the trick:

Here the matcher has to match a view which has a parent with id `action_bar` and is an ImageView.

```
onView(childOf(withId(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.action_bar),
            withClassName(is(ImageButton.class.getName()))))
            .perform(click());
```

the method `childOf` is as follows:

```
Matcher<View> childOf(Matcher<View> parentMatcher,
        Matcher<View> childMatcher) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
             // creation of description left as an exercise
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if (view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                return parentMatcher.matches(parent) && childMatcher
                        .matches(view);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

The method allows one to use a variety of child `ViewMatcher`, so you can use custom view matcher if in need.

### Refs:

1. espresso [custom-matcher sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/CustomMatcherSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/CustomMatcherSample/HintMatcher.java)